# Default value in selected dropdown with CPT

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, selectedvalue, dropdownlistfor

I researched but did not find right answer to my question

I have custom post type for states, cities and countries and would like to set the default value in the country list for "Argentina", but do not know how to solve it.

See my code:

```
<select name="pais" class="pais-select">

                <option value="">País</option>
                <?php
                    $pais = diretorio_request('pais');
                    foreach(diretorio_countries() as $country) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $country; ?>"<?php echo ($pais == $country) ? ' selected="1"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $country; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
```

I tried something like `selected = "selected"` but does not mark Argentina scored Zimbábue

Comment: Are you using custom fields in the CPT, or just in the associated template?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CPT for country and cities
I managed to solve with the modification in this code:

```
<option value="<?php echo $country; ?>" <?php if ($country == Brasil) echo 'selected="selected" ';?>><?php echo $country; ?></option>
```